# A characterization of spaces of measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Is it known any characterization of those ordered vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ that can be represented as spaces of all bounded $\mathbf{A}$-measurable functions $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$, for some set $X$ and a $\sigma$-field of sets $\mathbf{A}\subseteq 2^X$? I am looking for a characterization in the language of order and vector spaces. I am rather new to this topic; any references would be welcome.